# Python: How to read in a 16 bit .png grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv

I try to read in a 16bit grayscale image .png in python.

Neither

```
cv2.imread('test.png', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

nor

```
cv2.imread('test.png',-1)
```

is working. After reading in, my array is 8 bit. I'm confused, wether my image is a 16 bit image or not, because both prints me a 8 bit array (But I am pretty sure it is a 16 bit image). Is there a possibility to check it?

But does anyone know how to read in a 16 bit .png file to get an 16 bit array?

Comment: Check a PNG image with `pngcheck image.png`

Comment: ´cv2.imread('test.png', -cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)´ it's still not working. It's still a 8 bit array

Comment: If you right click on the image in windows and go to properties it should tell you how many bits your bitmap is

Comment: I tried `pngcheck test.png`and it says invalid syntax. How do I use this code sample?

Comment: GPPK thank you. I checked it and it is 8 bit. So the error is that it isn't 16 bit! MarkSetchell so it should work with your code sample with the right picture. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkSetchell What? `-cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` becomes -2, and there's no such valid `imread` parameter, it just incidentally ends up doing almost the same thing as plain `IMREAD_ANYDEPTH`. `-2` in binary works out as `0x11111110`, and the value is mostly used as a bitmap (only `IMREAD_UNCHANGED` is teated differently). So what you suggest is equivalent to `IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL | IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2 | IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_4 | IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_8 | IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION` .. and that surely doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Fortunately standard OpenCV builds don't tend to have GDAL, so that's ignored, the 3 reduction flags are also ignored since the flags are negative, ignoring orientation probably doesn't matter here due to no Exif. Finally it looks like the core of the problem was that the input image wasn't 16 bit in the first place. | Please remove that comment, I just ran into someone mindlessly copying this in another question.

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you for pointing that out - not sure what I was thinking 3 years ago, but I have deleted it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine with `cv2.imread('test.png', -cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for sharing back your findings with the community.

Comment: @Anja :- Python: How to read in a 16 bit .dcm grayscale image using PIL i,e PILLOW Library.?

Comment: No, this is just plain wrong, see my comments on the question.